# File Not Found - Where are sound files saved?

Tags: java, android

I'm following an example app code at 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/index.html

Whenever I try to run the code that begins to record audio, it fails saying the file cannot be found.  I'm running this with the emulator set to Android 2.1.  I'm really trying to find out:

1) Shouldn't the code create the file if it does not exist?
2) Where is it?  Stepping through the code says it's at "/sdcard/recordertest.3gp".  I can't seem to find that directory anywhere, so that may be the problem as well.

Please help!!!  Thanks.

Applicable code is below:

```
public RecorderTest() {
    mFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    mFileName += "/recordertest.3gp";
}


private void startRecording() {
    mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);
    mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

    try {
        mRecorder.prepare();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
    }

    mRecorder.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE">
```

in the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

A number of things to look at:

- You could be getting the path incorrect.  The most robust way to implement the file path calculation is.  (This is probably NOT the problem, but it is tidier this way ... and it gives you a `myFile` object for testing later on.)

---

```
// This avoids assumptions on what the pathname separator is
File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File myFile = new File(dir, "recordertest.3gp");

mFileName = myFile.getAbsolutePath();

// ... and write the pathname to your log so that 
// you can confirm it is what you expect
```

---

- Check that your application has permission to create / write files to that path.
- Check that your application is actually getting past the point in the code where it should have created the file.
- After the application has gotten past that point, use `File.exists()` (on the `myFile` object) to check if the file has been created.
- Check the log using `logcat` ...